# how to select special fields in query in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to join 3 tables (movies, comments, users) in my cakephp 3 controller and select only some special fields. I tested different solutions. I surfed a lot, but I could not solve it. Actually I need to show the last 3 comments on member profile.

Below is controller :

```
$movietbl = TableRegistry::get('Services.Movies');
        $movies = $movietbl->find()
                ->contain([
                    'Comments' => function($q) {
                        return $q->autoFields(false)
                                ->select([ 'id' , 'title' , 'comments']);
                    },
                    'Userscomments' => function($q) {
                        return $q->autoFields(false)
                                ->select(['lname', 'fname', 'id']);
                    }])
                        ->where(['Movies.user_id' => $this->getUserId()])
                        ->limit(3);
                $this->set('movies', $movies);
                $this->set('userId', $this->getUserId());
```

below is MoviesTable

```
$this->belongsToMany('Userscomments', [
            'className' => 'Services.Users',
            'joinTable'=>'comments',
            'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        ]);
    }
```

but it returns all of fields. What should I do now?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to confirm am I get it right: `Movies hasMany-> <-belongsTo Comments`, `Users hasMany-> <-belongsTo Comments`. And there is a profile page for every user, it shows 3 comments of a movie commented by this user.

Comment: Not me, if you think it's me. btw is the above description right?

Comment: @Tsumannai I am sorry. I know you did not downvote , I read your comment. I don't who downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many changes , finally my action works. I change the entry view of join. It works very well :) but I don't why. I used something like this solution on my previous code. However , it works now

```
 $coomentbl = TableRegistry::get('Services.Comments');
            $comments = $coomentbl->find('all',['fields'=>['id','comments','created']])->select(['Users.fname','Users.lname' ,'Users.imgname' ,'Users.username'])
           ->contain([

            'Users' => function($q) {
                            return $q->autoFields(false);
                        }
            , 'Movies'=> function($q) {
                            return $q->autoFields(false)
                                    ->where([['Movies.user_id' => $this->getUserId()]]);
                        }
            ])->order(['Comments.created' => 'DESC'])
                    ->limit(5)->toArray();
            $this->set('comments', $comments);
            $this->set('userId', $this->getUserId());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `autoFields(false)` *after* the `select()`:

```
$movietbl = TableRegistry::get('Services.Movies');
$movies = $movietbl->find()
    ->contain([
        'Comments' => function($q) {
            return $q->select([ 'id' , 'title' , 'comments'])
                ->autoFields(false);
        },
        'Userscomments' => function($q) {
            return $q->select(['lname', 'fname', 'id'])
                ->autoFields(false);
        }])
    ->where(['Movies.user_id' => $this->getUserId()])
    ->limit(3);
$this->set('movies', $movies);
$this->set('userId', $this->getUserId());
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
$movietbl = TableRegistry::get('Services.Movies');
$movies = $movietbl->find()
    ->contain([
        'Comments' => [
            'fields'=>[ 'id' , 'title' , 'comments']
        ],
        'Userscomments' =>[
            'fields'=>['lname', 'fname', 'id']
        ]
    ])
    ->where(['Movies.user_id' => $this->getUserId()])
    ->limit(3);
$this->set('movies', $movies);
$this->set('userId', $this->getUserId());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the filed names for the `select()` method.

It is in the cookbook: 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-all-fields-from-a-table

You can add the model names for multi table select in modelName.fieldName format.

```
$movietbl->find()->select(['Movies.title', 'Comments.id'])
```

Comment: As it mentioned it is for Selecting All Fields From _**a Table**_ . In my situation 3 tables participate in joins